# Retrofit not returning, event when the response is 200

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

I can see. the response from the logs since I have added a logger to my okhttp3 client, but for some reason, nothing happens after that. No error, nothing. I have tried on the virtual device and the physical one.
`retrofit 2.3, gson 2.8.6`
Here is my interceptor

> ```
> @Override
> public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
>
>     try {
>         Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
>         Request request = chain.request();
>
>         AppLogger.d("url from interceptor:" + response.request().url());
>         AppLogger.d("request headers from interceptor:" + response.request().headers());
>         AppLogger.d("response code from interceptor:" + response.code());
>         int responseCode = response.code();
>         String oldToken = mPreferencesHelper.getToken();
>         if (responseCode == ERROR_NETWORK) {
>             showNetworkError();
>         } else if (responseCode == 401 || responseCode == 403) {
>             if (oldToken != null || request.header(ApiStatics.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER) != null) {
>                 tryRefreshToken();
>                 response = chain.proceed(request);
>
>             } else {
>                 openAuthActivity();
>             }
>         } else if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
>             if (response.body() != null) {
>
>                 try {
>
>                     onWeoutResponseErrorListener.onNext(response.body());
>                 } catch (OnErrorNotImplementedException e) {
>                     AppLogger.d(e, "ServerResponseInterceptor");
>                 } catch (NullPointerException e) {
>                     AppLogger.d(e, "ServerResponseINterceptor");
>                 }
>             } else AppLogger.e(new NullPointerException(), "server returned no body ");
>         }
>         return response;
>     }catch (NullPointerException e){
>         AppLogger.d(e, "ServerResponseInterceptor");
>         openAuthActivity();
>
>         Response.Builder responseBuilder = new Response.Builder();
>         responseBuilder.code(404).message(e.getMessage()).request(chain.request()).protocol(Protocol.HTTP_2);
>         return  responseBuilder.build();
>     }
>
> }
> ```

I can see all the logs from both AppLogger and the interceptor I added on Okhttp3 client. But neither onResponse nor OnFailure get called.

My request below

> ```
> Call<PlaceListResponse> call = dataManager.getApiHelper().getPlacesApiHelper().getPlaces(pagePlace, searchQuery, null, mPlaceFilter, null, null, null);
>     AppLogger.d(call.request().url().host());
>     call.enqueue(new Callback<PlaceListResponse>() {
>         @Override
>         public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<PlaceListResponse> call, @NonNull Response<PlaceListResponse> response) {
>             updateLoadingStatus(false);
>             isLoadingNextPagePlaces.postValue(false);
>             AppLogger.d(TAG + " response places: " + response.body());
>             if (response.code() == 200) {
>                 if (response.body() != null) {
>                     PlaceListResponse responseBody = response.body();
>                     hasNextPlacesPage = responseBody.getNext() != null;
>                     List<PlaceListResult> places = responseBody.getResults();
>                     if (places.size() > 0 & places.size() >10) places = places.subList(0,11);
>                     List<WeOutItemViewModel> placesViewModels = WeOutPlacesViewModel.this.getPlaceItemViewModels(places);
>                     List<Double> sortedDistances = WeOutPlacesViewModel.this.getSortedDistances(placesViewModels);
>                     List<WeOutGroupedViewModels> weOutGroupedViewModels = 
> getGroupedViewModels(placesViewModels,
> sortedDistances);
>                     updateReceiver.postValue(weOutGroupedViewModels);
>                 } else {
>                     AppLogger.d(TAG + " nothing loaded");
>                 }
>
>             } else if (response.code() >= 400 && response.code() < 500 && response.code() != 404) {
>                 Timber.d("unregistered:", response.message());
>                 unregisteredAction();
>             } else { //                    TODO:
>                 Timber.d("event error", response.toString(), WeOutViewModel.class.getName());
>                 Timber.e("event error" + response.code());
>                 Timber.e("event response header" + response.headers());
>                 Timber.e("event request header" + response.raw().request().headers());
>                 Timber.e("event request header" + response.raw().request().header("Authorization"));
>             }
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onFailure(Call<PlaceListResponse> call, Throwable t) {
>             updateLoadingStatus(false); //                isLoadingPlaces.set(false);
>             isLoadingNextPagePlaces.postValue(false);
>             Timber.e(TAG + t.getMessage() + "error loading places");
>             Timber.e(t, TAG);
>             call.cancel();
>             errorListener.postValue(ERROR_NETWORK);
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: have you found any solutions to it? I am having exactly same issue you described.

Comment: Yes. It was due to the line ```updateLoadingStatus```.  I wasn't updating the baseviewmodel